# BST with a linked list between nodes

Tags: tree, linked-list, binary-search-tree, treeset

I'm attempting to implement a TreeSet using an (unbalanced) BST. I also want to maintain an inorder doubly-linked list for all the nodes in the tree.

```
TreeSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>();
set.add(10);
set.add(5);
set.add(15);
set.add(12);
// The linked list would be 5 <-> 10 <-> 12 <-> 15
```

The linked list is maintained with the help of 2 sentinel nodes, a head and a tail node. So to traverse the linked list you'd start at the head node and check its `.next` property.

```
class Node<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {
    private Node<T> left, right,
                    prev, next;
}
```

I have a recursive `add` method which like this;

```
boolean add(T data) {
    int oldSize = getSize();
    root = add(data, root, head, tail);
    return getSize() != oldSize;
}


Node<T> add(T data, Node<T> n, Node<T> low, Node<T> high) {
    if (n == nullNode) {
        n = new Node<T>(data);
        n.left = n.right = nullNode;
        // But what do I do now to update the linked list?
    } else {
        int result = compare(data, n.data);
        if (result < 0) {
            n.left = add(data, n.left, low, n);
        } else if (result > 0) {
            n.right = add(data, n.right, n, high);
        }
    }

    return n;
}
```

where `low` and `high` set the boundaries of where in the linked list the new node will be inserted.

I'm having issues maintaining the `next` and `prev` properties of my nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to keep track the previous node. i.e. the node that was visited previously.

This is done by finding the inorder predecessor. Inorder predecessor is the right most leaf of the left subtree of a node.

In the same way, you have to find the inorder successor for setting the next node.

There are exceptions here, of course -  what if the node is the leaf? 
In that case inorder predecessor will be the first ancestor whose right subtree will contain the current node. Similarly, for finding the next node.

Have a look at inorder predecessor and successor concepts online.

**Note**: This is not the most efficient method but should be a good way to get started.